# Accessing iPhone's Contact List via mobile browser

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova

Is there a way to access iPhone's Contact List via browser like Safari?

I researched Phonegap for this permission, but I think it's not possible via Phonegap.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible ([at least it was possible in iOS 4.2.1 and 4.3](http://www.iclarified.com/entry/index.php?enid=14229)), but you have to be quite a bit of a hacker to achieve it ;)